# Can I grab historic weather data from the api?

Tags: here-api, weather-api

My use case would be to send an API request in the morning, based on a lat/long.
I would hope to get back weather data that was recorded every 4 hours.

Can't find any documentation, is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the existing APIs available for weather data, we are not providing any historic weather data API. However if the demand from users surge, this can be developed as we have this data available.

Please drop your request at

> www.here.com/contact?cid=www.here.com_navigatyesion-company

Comment: I don't see a feature request area. Can you please add to your internal list? It's something that all other weather API's offer, except for yours.